# Dentro de uma estrutura de decisão, a ordem dos termos altera o resultado?

Tags: c#, java

Existe alguma diferença entre:

```
if (variavelA == variavelB)
```

e

```
if (variavelB == variavelA)
```

Em Java e C#, existe alguma diferença entre os exemplos? Ressalto que a pergunta não se limita apenas ao operador `==`, mas a todos que podem ser usados dentro de estruturas de decisão.

Comment: Em que linguagem? Isso varia.

Comment: Qualquer linguagem: Java, C#, VB, ShellScript, Ruby, PHP...

Comment: O problema é a reticências. Não posso falar por todas estas linguagens. Mas em C++, por exemplo, a ordem dos operandos pode fazer diferença dependendo de como o operador foi implementado. Não posso garantir que todas linguagens `"abc" == "abcdef"` e `"abcdef" == "abc"` dê resultados iguais. Na verdade conheço que poucas pessoas conhecem que uma forma ligeiramente diferente dá `true` em um caso e `false` em outro. Talvez se explicar mais onde quer chegar com esta pergunta, dê para produzir respostas mais interessantes.

Comment: Em PHP `1 == "1"` dá `true` mas `1 === "1"` dá `false`. A questão é sobre o `if`, sobre o operador de igualdade, o operador específico `==` ou sobre operações relacionais? Acho complicado responder sem ter linguagem ou tipo da variável conhecido, além de ter claro sobre o que é a pergunta.

Comment: Outro fator podebser como a linguagem trata o nulo ou variável não iniciada, também atentar que algumas linguagens convertem tipos de forma automática e isto poderia alterar resultados de alguma forma, fora isto "igual" deveria ser "igual".

Comment: No caso, a pergunta é relacionada à ordem dos termos.

Comment: Pelo menos já sabemos que a questão nada tem a ver com `if`. Ordem dos termos em que? Ordem especificamente no `==`? E se a linguagem não tiver exatamente esse operador? E se ela tiver outras forma de operador de igualdade? E se usar um `<` ou `>=`? Isto é importante para a pergunta ou só o `==` mesmo?

Comment: "Independente de compiladores ou linguagens" não dá pra responder! Ninguém conhece todas as linguagens que existem, e é bem possível que exista alguma onde a ordem dos fatores faz diferença (*eu* não conheço nenhuma, mas eu conheço poucas linguagens). Não existe uma definição universal do operador para todas as linguagens, cada uma implementa isso com seus próprios termos.

Comment: E nem falei da tipagem. De que tipo são os 2 "termos"? Em algumas linguagens isso pode não fazer diferença, tem linguagem que faz. Estou tentando salvar a pergunta, para isso essas questões precisam ser revolvidas. Caso contrário, ela é muito ampla.

Comment: A ordem da avaliação dos dois lados da igualdade também pode afetar o resultado. Imagine que um operando é uma variável, e o outro é uma função que muda o valor dessa variável... Qualquer linguagem que possua efeitos colaterais está sujeita a essa situação (talvez exceto se a linguagem fizer uma separação rígida entre **procedimento** e **função** - e não deixar que subrotinas com efeitos colaterais retornem valores). E isso sem entrar no mérito de *weak typing*, sobrecarga de operadores, etc.

Comment: Isso vai depender da linguagem!!! então se pudesse melhorar a questão é limitar quais! quem sabe melhoria e seria de grande valia essa questão @Patrick.

Comment: Ok, fiz algumas alterações e limitei a duas linguagens que uso.

Comment: Melhorou bastante. Ainda tenho dúvidas se é fácil responder porque para ter uma resposta correta, a pessoa precisa entender sobre as duas linguagens . Eu não conseguira falar apropriadamente sobre Java. E se for para ter respostas separadas, talvez caia neste problema http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/289/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-podem-ter-multiplas-respostas. Mesmo para responder em C# apesar de trazer um bom aprendizado, no início das pesquisas já percebi que pode ter tantos casos fora do comum, que eu duvido que vou cobrir todos.

Comment: Então a resposta seria: em condições normais a ordem da igualdade e desigualdade não afeta nada. Mas tem inúmeras situações realmente extraordinárias que podem fazer isso não ser verdade. Em outros operadores relacionais já pode fazer toda diferença. Simples: `1 > 3` e `3 > 1` produzem resultados obviamente diferentes.

Comment: E quanto a `1 > 3` e `3 < 1`?

Comment: @Patrick se você troca o operador você está fazendo outra comparação completamente diferente, você já não está mais falando de ordem de termos na mesma operação.

Comment: Não sei se termos seria a palavra mais adequada... Mas em suma, seria isso: operadores e valores.

Comment: Eu tentei salvar. Esta pergunta é muito ampla e sem um capítulo completo de um livro ela só pode ser respondida parcialmente (as respostas mostram isso), mesmo depois das edições e tentativas de esclarecimento (o que eu acho que piorou a situação, ficou mais amplo ainda). O problema é muito complexo. A única forma de responder sucintamente é "tudo pode acontecer". Apenas um exemplo de coisas que podem afetar pode ser encontrada em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18910/qual-a-diferenca-no-uso-do-metodo-equals-para-o-operador/18920#18920. Muitos outros fatores existem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A ordem pode alterar o resultado em linguagens onde há **sobrecarga de operadores**.

## Diferenças com operadores sobrecarregados

Em C#, por exemplo, você pode criar uma implementação específica para o comparador `==` e [vários outros operadores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx). Veja um [exemplo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```csharp
public static DBBool operator ==(DBBool x, DBBool y) 
{
   if (x.value == 0 || y.value == 0) return dbNull;
   return x.value == y.value? dbTrue: dbFalse;
}
```

Então `variavelB` e `variavelA` podem ser de tipos diferentes e, consequentemente, o método sobrecarregado `==` pode ter sido em implementado diferentemente em um ou até nos dois tipos.

Algumas linguagens que implementam sobrecarga de operadores os utilizam como simples chamadas a métodos. Em Ruby, por exemplo, você pode inclusive chamar o operador como um método qualquer.

Considere os exemplos abaixo. Ambas as operações de soma resultam no valor `3`:

```rb
a = 1 + 2 
b = 1.+(2)
```

O mesmo serve para a comparação:

```rb
if a == b
if a.==(b)
```

Isso pode ser diferente de:

```
if b == a
if b.==(a)
```

Obviamente os exemplos acima pode diferir se `a` e `b` forem classes diferentes.

## Sem diferenças quando não é possível estender a linguagem

Já em linguagens como Java ou PHP, a ordem de comparação das variáveis não é importante, pois o operador `==` irá sempre comparar:

1. Os valores, para variáveis primitivas.
2. Se forem objetos, se os dois apontam para a mesma instância.

## Considerações finais

Os conceitos aqui apresentados podem variar sutilmente ou bruscamente de uma linguagem para outra ou mesmo entre versões da própria linguagem.

O importante é que o desenvolvedor compreenda o mecanismo atual que a linguagem usa por debaixo dos panos.

Comment: Concordo, sem estender a linguagem o resultado tem que ser igual e se estender, pode fazer qualquer coisa na realidade...

Comment: Então não é possível sobrecarregar ou sobrescrever um operador em Java?

Comment: @Patrick Não. Isso me assustou um pouco quando comecei a trabalhar com a linguagem. Basicamente o que se faz é usar o método `equals()` para comparar igualdade e `compareTo()` para saber se um objeto é maior que outro. Obviamente a ordem importa e o objeto da esquerda não pode ser nulo. Além disso, classes numéricas como [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) implementam métodos com `add`, `subtract`, `multiply` e `divide`. Isso torna muito difícil criar novos tipos e usá-los como os primitivos, mas é algo que se acostuma.

Answer (score 2):

Vou dar uma resposta parcial, voltada para .NET e Mono.

O comportamento do operador `==` varia da seguinte forma:

- Para tipos por referência, ele verifica se as referências são iguais, i.e.: se ambos os objetos comparados são na verdade o mesmo;
- Para tipos por valor, ele irá executar uma implementação de igualdade própria do tipo. Todo tipo por valor tem que ter sua própria lógica de igualdade. Experimente definir um `struct`, e depois criar duas instâncias desse `struct` e tentar verificar se são iguais `==`. Seu código não irá nem compilar ;) Note que em geral os structs nativos do Framework (`bool`, `int`, `float` etc.) possuem implementação própria para esse operador.

Note que em ambos os casos é possível sobrecarregar o operador `==`. Na verdade, é **obrigatório** sobrecarregá-lo no segundo caso, se você for utilizá-lo no seu código.

Se você sobrecarregar o operador, aí a lógica de igualdade é completamente sua. Você sabe quais são os operadores da esquerda e da direita, e pode fazer o que quiser com eles. Nesse caso, se a ordem importa ou não é uma decisão do desenvolvedor. Se o operador não for sobrecarregado, a ordem realmente não faz diferença.

O mesmo vale para os operadores de comparação (`>`, `<`, `>=` e `<=`), se você se refere a comparações que devem ser equivalentes, i.e.: `a < b` em relação a  `b > a`. Depende apenas dos operadores terem sido sobrecarregados, e da lógica que foi usada na sobrecarga. Para os tipos comparáveis padrão em .NET e Mono (`int`, `float` e até mesmo `DateTime`), a comparação é estritamente numérica, então para esses tipos tanto faz.

Comment: concordo, se o operador não é sobrecarregado, o resultado é o mesmo ou nem existe (porque não se trata mais de uma igualdade e sim de uma extensão do conceito para comparar objetos)

Answer (score 1):

Para o operador "igual" (`==`) a ordem das condições (variáveis,valores e etc) não alteram o resultado.

**Independente  da linguagem.**

Comment: Esta informação não é verdadeira. Existem linguagens que faz ou pelo menos pode fazer diferença.

Comment: @bigown será que o Apolo não está se referindo apenas as linguagens mencionadas pelo OP?

Comment: @Renan a pergunta foi editada (dê uma olhada no histórico), quando ele respondeu era outra pergunta e claramente ele respondeu em cima desta premissa anterior. Ele até destacou isso na resposta. Mas a resposta também não responde algo correto para estas duas linguagens. Comecei pesquisar e o assunto é complicado.

Comment: +1 - Acho que só pode fazer diferença se o conceito de igualdade for redefinido (sobrecarga de operador, igualdade entre estruturas ou expressões que se alteram quando são avaliadas por exemplo). Por definição matemática a igualdade é simétrica (portanto por definição (a == b) tem que ter o mesmo resultado de (b == a). O que não obedecer não é mais igualdade. Na realidade para contradizer, é só mostrar um exemplo numa linguagem onde uma igualdade (não modificada) tenha resultado diferente quando avaliada simetricamente e até agora não vi nenhum.

Comment: @bigown você poderia exemplificar uma linguagem onde a ordem das "variáveis" influenciam no resultado da condição de igualdade?
Exatamente laurent, minha resposta está embasada no conceito matemático de igualdade.

Comment: C++, Clipper, e qualquer outra que possua *overload* de operador e o programador queira fazer que haja diferença. Sei que tem outras mas não vou ficar pesquisando, esse é o problema de perguntas que são muito amplas e deveriam ser fechadas.

Answer (score 0):

Em Java não faz diferença nenhuma.

Já fiz varias vezes usando o operador de igualdade `==` e o resultado é o mesmo