# Qual a diferença no uso do método Equals para o operador ==?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, operadores, método

Qual a diferença no uso do método `Equals` para o operador `==` em situações de comparação entre (1) tipos valor e (2) tipos por referência?

Comment: Só uma dica, em C# não existe o conceito de tipos primitivos. Existem tipos por valor (`struct` e `enum`) e tipos por referência (`class`, `interface`, `delegate`, etc.). Veja mais em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14490/alocacao-de-memoria-em-c-tipos-valor-e-tipos-referencia/14492#14492

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Segundo a Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) em texto escrito pelo [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet):

**O método `Equals` é apenas um método virtual definido na [`System.Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)**, e pode ser sobrepostos por quaisquer classes que optar por fazê-lo. **O `==` é um operador que pode ser sobrecarregado por classes**, quando normalmente ela tem comportamento de identidade.

Para tipos de referência, onde `==` não foi sobrecarregado, ele compara se duas referências se referem ao mesmo objeto, que é exatamente o que a implementação de Equals faz em `System.Object`.

Tipos de valor não fornecem uma sobrecarga para `==` por padrão. No entanto, a maioria dos tipos de valores fornecidos pelo .NET fornecem sua própria sobrecarga. A implementação padrão de [`Equals()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) para um tipo de valor é fornecido pelo [`ValueType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), e usa reflexão para fazer a comparação, o que torna significativamente mais lento do que uma implementação específica para o tipo normalmente seria. Essa implementação chama também `Equals()` em pares de referências dentro dos dois valores que estão sendo comparados.

No entanto, a principal diferença entre os dois tipos de comparação em condições normais de uso (onde é improvável que você defina seus próprios tipos de valor) é o polimorfismo. Os operadores são sobrecarregados, não sobrepostos (*override*), o que significa que a menos que o compilador saiba que deve chamar a versão mais específica, ele só chamará a versão de identidade. Para ilustrar isso, aqui está um exemplo:

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        // cria duas variáveis iguais mas distintas uma da outra
        string a = new string(new char[] {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});
        string b = new string(new char[] {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'});
        WriteLine (a == b);
        WriteLine (a.Equals(b));
        // o mesmo teste usando os mesmo dados mas como variáveis do tipo `Object`
        object c = a;
        object d = b;
        WriteLine (c == d);
        WriteLine (c.Equals(d));
    }
}
```

O resultado é:

```
True
True
False
True
```

A terceira linha é falsa porque o compilador só pode chamar a versão não sobrecarregada de `==` já que ele não sabe que o conteúdo de `c` e `d` são as duas referências de *strings*. Como eles são referências a diferentes cordas, o operador identidade retorna false.

Então, quando você deve usar o operador? A regra básica é que, para quase todos os tipos de referência, o uso é igual a quando você quer testar a igualdade em vez de identidade de referência. A exceção é para *strings* - comparar *strings* com `==` faz as coisas bem mais simples e mais legível, mas é preciso lembrar que ambos os lados do operador deve ser expressões do tipo *string*, para conseguir que comparação funcione corretamente.

Para tipos de valores, normalmente usa-se `==` para melhor legibilidade. Fica mais complicado se um tipo de valor, fornece uma sobrecarga para `==` que age de forma diferente para `Equals`, mas isto seria tal situação muito mal projetada.

---

Resumindo isso tudo:

Você escolhe o que cada um deve fazer de acordo com a expectativa intuitiva do programador.

O que o programador espera comparar quando ele usa um `==`? É isto que esta comparação deve fazer, não importa a maneira de fazer. Ele pode comparar os seus membros ou as referências. Ele deve **comparar a identidade**.

Já o método **`Equals()` espera que a comparação seja baseada no valor do tipo**. Ou seja, baseado no seu valor, nos membros relevantes para o tipo.

É bom lembrar que existe um método **[`ReferenceEquals()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que tem a função de comparar especificamente as referências dos objetos**.

É comum o operador `==` escolher usar a implementação do `Equals()` ou a implementação do `ReferenceEquals()`.

O operador `==` é estático e funciona mais como se fosse um método de extensão.

Há casos em que o `Equals()` tem três versões possíveis para escolha do compilador:

- o método estático de `object` (`Equals(object, object)`);
- o método virtual vindo de `object` (`Equals(object)`);
- o método que implementa `IEquatable<short>` (`Equals(short)` ).

Por isso inconsistências podem ocorrer.

## Inconsistências

```
int myInt = 1;
short myShort = 1;
object objInt1 = myInt;
object objInt2 = myInt;
object objShort = myShort;
WriteLine(myInt == myShort);          // cenário 1 true
WriteLine(myShort == myInt);          // cenário 2 true
WriteLine(myInt.Equals(myShort));     // cenário 3 true
WriteLine(myShort.Equals(myInt));     // cenário 4 false!
WriteLine(objInt1 == objInt1);        // cenário 5 true
WriteLine(objInt1 == objShort);       // cenário 6 false!!
WriteLine(objInt1 == objInt2);        // cenário 7 false!!!
WriteLine(Equals(objInt1, objInt2));  // cenário 8 true
WriteLine(Equals(objInt1, objShort)); // cenário 9 false!?!
```

## Strings

Este é um tipo que exemplifica bem como a semântica é mais importante que a linearidade do funcionamento. Veja os exemplos:

```
string s1 = "abc";
string s2 = "abc";
WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2)); //retorna true
```

Isso ocorre por causa de uma técnica chama [*interning*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164960/101) que tenta reaproveitar uma alocação existente de uma *string* idêntica a que se tenta alocar novamente. Mas esta é uma exceção. Veja agora:

```
string s3 = "abc";
string s4t = "ab";
string s4 = s4t + "c";
WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(s3, s4)); //retorna false
WriteLine(s3 == s4); //retorna true
```

Se o operador `==` adotasse a comparação de referências como costuma acontecer com os tipos por referência o resultado seria estranho. Como a comparação de igualdade de "abc" e "abc" pode retornar `false`? Não pode, por isso a comparação é feita em cima da identidade, que no caso do tipo *string* é o seu valor e não sua referência.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/k8OGlf). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2qPb4P). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/Equals.cs).

Comment: `em texto escrito pelo Jon Skeet` +1!

Answer (score 15):

Basicamente funciona assim:

- Se o tipo é primitivo (ou seja, `Boolean` (`bool`), `Byte` (`byte`), `SByte` (`sbyte`), `Int16` (`short`), `UInt16`, `Int32` (`int`), UInt32 (`uint`), `Int64` (`long`), UInt64 (`ulong`), `IntPtr`, `UIntPtr`, `Char` (`char`), `Double` (`double`), ou `Single` (`single`)), a comparação entre duas variáveis será por valor;
- Qualquer outro objeto, a comparação será propriedade a propriedade, mas neste caso, é bastante fácil um objeto não ser igual a outro.

  - Há também a possibilidade de testar se as referências das variáveis são iguais, utilizando o método `System.Object.ReferenceEquals()`;
  - Se for usado o operador `==` para comparação entre dois objetos, o método utilizado na verdade será o `ReferenceEquals`.

    - A exceção para este caso são `structs`. em que é obrigatório sobrecarregar o operador `==` para poder usá-lo.

Neste caso, o que o C# oferece é a possibilidade de reescrever o método `Equals` pra alguma classe em específico, preferencialmente para flexibilizar as regras de comparação.

Comment: `Se for usado o operador == para comparação entre dois objetos, o método utilizado na verdade será o ReferenceEquals` Quando o tipo for por referência. Para structs é obrigatório sobrecarregar o `==` para poder usá-lo. BTW +1

Comment: Verdade. Vou complementar a resposta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Se por tipos "primitivos" você quer dizer aqueles para os quais o Framework têm sinônimos, como `System.Int32` (`int`), `System.Boolean` (`bool`), `System.DateTime` (`DateTime`) etc.

Se forem structs, você precisa necessariamente sobrecarregar o operador `==` para poder usá-lo. Já o método `Equals`, ao menos para duas instâncias do mesmo tipo, irá comparar os valores dos membros do struct, e retornar verdadeiro caso haja um match membro a membro. Se ambos os operadores darão o mesmo resultado ou não, depende da sua implementação da sobrecarga do `==`.

Já para tipos por referência, o operador `==`, não sendo sobrecarregado, irá comparar as referências, não os valores em si. Dessa forma, dois objetos equivalentes (i.e.: uma instância de um tipo qualquer e um clone profundo) podem ser "diferentes" quando comparados com o `==`. Já o método `Equals`, que também pode ser sobrecarregado, faz a comparação membro a membro para diversos tipos nativos - mas isso é uma questão de implementação de cada tipo, e não uma comparação bruta como a dos structs.

Answer (score -1):

Caso voce tenha um objeto do tipo nulo, o Equals não irá funcionar. Por exemplo:

```
    String nome = null
    if (nome.equals("Nome"){
       //Faça alguma coisa
    }
```

Este código vai retornar um erro NullPointerException porque se nome é nulo não é possivel acessar o método equals. Para tipos primitivos, recomenda-se usar o ==.

EDIT: Perdão, respondi como se fosse em Java. Acredito que talvez se aplique a C#

Comment: `Caso voce tenha um objeto do tipo nulo` Nulo não é um tipo. E o código vai dar erro porque você está chamando um método de uma referência nula. O mesmo vale para Java, só muda o nome da exceção. Se `nome` tivesse um valor, você poderia passar nulo para o método Equals (que é com 'E' maiúsculo).