# Porquê que a comparação duma variável com None deve ser feita usando is ou is not

Tags: python-3.x

Estou usando `PyCharm` como IDE para criar os meus programas em *Python*, e a um certo ponto tive que fazer uma comparação entre um valor duma variável e `None`, e tentei faze-lo com o seguinte código:

```
if file == None: 
    print("Nothing opened")
```

mas o PyCharm me está avisando que a comparação dum valor duma variável com o None deveria ser feita usando **is** ou **is not**. Porquê?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18910/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-no-uso-do-m%C3%A9todo-equals-para-o-operador

Comment: Veja também: **[Em Python, quais as consequências em usar 'is' no lugar de '=='](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38104/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O operador `==` testa por **igualdade**, enquanto o `is` testa por **identidade**. Em outras palavras, `x is y` só retornará `True` se `x` e `y` forem o mesmo objeto (e não meramente "iguais"):

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]   # x é um objeto
>>> y = [1, 2, 3]   # y é outro
>>> print(x == y)   # eles são iguais (mesmo tipo, mesmo tamanho, mesmos elementos)
True
>>> print(x is y)   # mas não são "o mesmo objeto" - se mexer em um, o outro não é afetado
False
>>> z = x           # z é outra referência para o mesmo objeto x
>>> print(x is z)   # então eles são efetivamente "o mesmo objeto"
True
```

Quanto a comparar com `None`, muitas vezes sua intenção é saber se tal variável está realmente vazia - e não somente contém um valor que é "igual ao vazio":

```
>>> class Vazio(object):
...   def __eq__(self, obj):
...     return obj is None
...
>>> v = Vazio()
>>> print(v == None)
True
>>> print(v is None)
False

>>> v == v    # Pela regra "louca" do Vazio.__eq__, v é diferente de si próprio!
False
>>> v is v    # Mas obviamente, ainda é o mesmo objeto
True
```

Se sua *intenção* for mesmo comparar por igualdade com `None`, não há problemas em se usar o `==`. Mas como raramente (nunca?) isso é útil na prática, quando se vê um código usando `== None` ou `!= None` normalmente se assume que foi um engano do programador, e não algo que ele fez propositalmente.

Answer (score 2):

Eles sao diferentes. O `==` invoca o metodo `__eq__` da classe a esquerda dele. Ja o `is` compara igualdade mesmo.

Nesse caso da na mesma, contudo.

Comment: sim. sem problemas. por isso ficaria estranho fazer `==` para o `None`, ja que e esquisito comparar um objeto com "nada" e sim "ser" nada XD

Comment: quando o `eq` nao for igual a comparação de igualdade.