# Em Python, quais as consequências em usar 'is' no lugar de '=='

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

As duas formas abaixo retornam `True`, mas quais as consequências disso num código mais complexo?

```
>>> a = '2'
>>> a is '2'  
>>> True
>>> a == '2' 
>>> True
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As consequências dependem do objetivo do código. `is` e `==` não são sinônimos, e não podem simplesmente ser trocados como se fossem.

O que ocorre é que, em muitas situações, os dois retornam o mesmo valor quando substituidos, dando uma ilusão errônea de que se comportam da mesma maneira, mas a natureza das comparações é completamente diferente.

- O `is` verifica se os dois nomes apontam para **o mesmo** objeto armazenado na memória

  (Maria e Joana moram na mesma casa, portanto têm o mesmo endereço)
- o `==` compara o **conteúdo** armazenado em cada um dos dois nomes, independente de apontarem para o mesmo objeto, ou para objetos diferentes.

  (A casa da Maria é idêntica à casa do José, mesmos móveis, mesma cor, etc)

É muito importante que sejam levadas em conta as diferenças entre os dois operadores, para que o código se comporte como esperado. Para isto, segue uma explicação um pouco mais detalhada sobre cada um:

### O operador `is`:

Em Python, o operador `is` é o comparador de **instância** de objetos, e não de **valores**.

Por exemplo:

```
>>> x = [2, 3, 4]
>>> y = [2, 3, 4]
>>> x is y
```

Retorna

```
False
```

pois apesar dos valores serem iguais, se tratam de objetos completamente diferentes.

**`is` e *strings***

Não se iluda com este exemplo:

```
>>> x = "string"
>>> y = "string"
>>> x is y
True
>>> z = "str"+"ing"
>>> a is z
True
```

Neste caso, apesar da impressão da comparação com `is` se comportar identicamente à feita com `==`, o que está acontecendo aqui é outra coisa. O Python é "esperto" o suficiente para não alocar várias vezes valores repetidos de *string*, então ele aponta o nome do novo objeto para a *string* já armazenada anteriormente, efetivamente aproveitando os dados já alocados.

Strings normalmente devem ser comparadas com `==`, a não ser que você saiba exatamente o que está fazendo.

**`is` e alguns inteiros**

Olhe o exemplo a seguir:

```
>>> x = 256
>>> y = 256
>>> x is y
True

>>> x = 257
>>> y = 257
>>> x is y
False
```

Isto é devido a uma peculiaridade determinada por implementação: quando você usa números de -5 até 256, o Python já tem uma tabela de armazenamento interna, cujos objetos já estão criados nativamente e seu ID é aproveitado.

### O operador `==`:

O `==` é o comparador de valores, como na maior parte das linguagens. O objeto pode ser diferente, o que interessa para a comparação é o valor:

```
>>> x = 1278
>>> y = 1278
>>> x == y
```

Retorna:

```
True
```

### A função `id()`:

Se houver necessidade de *debugar* uma situação onde o `is` não se comporta como esperado, pode-se utilizar a função `id()` para se obter o ID interno dos objetos, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
>>> x = 257
>>> y = 257
>>> id(x)
12686128
>>> id(y)
12686140
```

### Comparando com `None`:

O `None` é um objeto especial em Python, e representa a ausência de valor, de certa forma como o `null` de algumas linguagens. Por se tratar de um objeto que representa a ausência, e não um valor em si, você sempre deve usar `x is None` e `x is not None`, e nunca `x == None` e `x != None`.

Atenção com este caso especial:

```
if ( x is None ):
```

Neste caso, um programador experiente em outras linguagens poderia se sentir tentado a usar simplesmente `if ( x )`, imaginando que o `None` já seria considerado falso. Assim como a comparação de valores não deve ser usada com o `None`, no `if` a verificação também requer o `is None` ou `is not None`

### Implementando a comparação em classes:

Os métodos que implementam a comparação `is` e `==` em Python são respectivamente `__is__` e `__eq__`, e neste caso, o programador deve ter plena consciência das diferenças mencionadas acima. A grosso modo, é algo nesta linha:

```
# O exemplo foi simplificado demasiadamente ;)
class X(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other
    def __is__(self, other):
        return self.value is other
```

Answer (score 9):

A resposta do Bacco é supercompleta, mas para quem quiser uma resposta mais resumida:

O `is` serve para comparar se duas coisas são exatamente o mesmo objeto na memória RAM do computador.

Já o `==` faz uma comparação a fundo do conteúdo dos objetos. Então se dois objetos em lugares diferentes na memória tiverem o mesmo conteúdo, o `==` detectará a igualdade, enquanto o `is` não.

Answer (score 2):

Um código vale mais do que mil palavras.

```
class Pessoa(object):
    def __init__(self, nome, idade):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade

joao = Pessoa("João Bom de Python", 16) # 0x1
alex = Pessoa("Alex Java", 23) # 0x2
clone_alex = alex # 0x2

print joao is alex # 0x1 == 0x2
print clone_alex is alex # 0x2 == 0x2
```

Mais um, estou empolgado:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3] # 0xC
>>> y = [1, 2, 3] # 0x18
>>> x is y # 0xC == 0x18
False
>>> x = y
>>> x is y # 0x18 == 0x18
True
```

Obs: Os endereços são exemplificativos apenas.