# Como saber se request.FILES está vazio?

Tags: python, django

Tenho um código no `Django` onde desejo fazer um upload de um arquivo vindo de um formulário.

Em um dado momento preciso verificar se existe o índice `"arquivo"` dentro da variável `request.FILES`

Eu fiz utilizando o método `has_key` da seguinte maneira (não reparem se o código estiver feio, pois sou iniciante no `python`):

```
import os

def upload(request):

    data = {}   

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if request.FILES.has_key('arquivo'):

            files = request.FILES['arquivo']

            path = 'upload'

            if not os.path.exists(path):
                os.makedirs(path)


            upload_path = path + '/' + files.name;

            with open(upload_path, 'w') as upload:
                upload.write(files.read())

            data["teste"] = "dados enviados"

        else:
            data["teste"] = "arquivo não preenchido"
    else:

        data["teste"] = "não enviado"


    return render(request, 'upload.html', data)
```

Porém, ao invés de verificar se um índice específico existe, eu gostaria de saber qual é a melhor maneira de verificar se `request.FILES` está vazio.

Eu tinha elaborado duas maneira para tentar fazer isso:

1) exemplo:

```
if request.FILES:
    #faça alguma coisa
```

2) exemplo:

```
if len(request.FILES) is not 0:
   #faça alguma coisa
```

Mas não sei se isso é apropriado. Estou aprendendo a linguagem agora e não quero começar fazendo gambiarras.

Ou seja: Existe alguma maneira melhor para verificar se `request.FILES` está vazio?

Comment: `if request.FILES:`, simplesmente. Não é errado fazer de outra forma, embora seu segundo exemplo [não deveria usar `is not`, e sim `!=`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38104/215).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como o atributo [`FILES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) do [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) é um dicionário, você pode verificá-lo de diversas formas:

```
files = {} 
if not files:
    print "Dicionario vazio!"

if not bool(files):
    print "Dicionario vazio!"

if len(files) == 0:
    print "Dicionario vazio!"
```

Comment: É um dicionário, de fato, mas na realidade não é um `dict` - e sim um `MultiValueDict`. Para um único arquivo não faz diferença, mas se o formulário tiver algum campo `<input type="file" multiple>` as coisas ficam... um pouquinho confusas! :P Pra efeito da resposta, não faz diferença, entretanto.

Answer (score 1):

Verificando se há qualquer arquivo sendo enviado pode ser utilizado conforme você colocou no seu exemplo `if request.FILES`

Poderia verificar especificamente também pode ser feito desta forma:

```
try:
    request.FILES['arquivo']
except KeyError:
    print 'arquivo não enviado'
else:
    pass
    # faz upload
```

ou

```
if request.FILES.get('arquivo', False):
    pass
    # faz upload
else:
    print 'arquivo não enviado'
```