# Como funciona o operador de identidade em Python?

Tags: python, operadores

Eu estou iniciando em Python e gostaria de fazer uma questão baseada no código abaixo:

**Caso 1**

```
x = 5
y = 5

print(x is y) # retorna True
```

**Caso 2**

```
x = "carro"
y = "carro"

print(x is y) # retorna True
```

**Caso 3:**

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,2,3]

print(x is y) # retorna False
```

Por que isso acontece? Eu já pesquisei esse assunto e sei que o operador de identidade `is` compara objetos e sua locação de memória e não seus valores - o que é feito pelo operador `==`.

Mas mesmo assim, eu não entendo por exemplo o porquê de inteiros e strings serem alocados ou apontarem para uma mesma locação de memória e listas não por algum motivo interno do Python, se isso for de fato verdade.

Comment: Talvez possa ajudar: [Em Python, quais as consequências em usar 'is' no lugar de '=='](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/38104/125486).