# Comportamento das diferentes formas de comparação em Java

Tags: java, operadores, equals

Se por exemplo eu tenho o código abaixo, eu estou comparando a referência dos objetos no caso `ex1` e `ex2` e não o objeto em si, correto?

```
Pessoa ex1 = new Pessoa();
Pessoa ex2 = new Pessoa();
if(ex1 == ex2)
{
    System.out.println("Igual");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("não é igual");
}
```

Aqui sempre é impresso que não é igual, sendo assim creio eu que estou comparando referências correto?

---

Minha outra dúvida é se isso é igual ao código acima que foi digitado:

```
Pessoa ex1 = new Pessoa();
Pessoa ex2 = new Pessoa();
if(ex1.equals(ex2))
{
    System.out.println("Igual");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("não é igual");
}
```

Comment: Perdoe o "anúncio" mas escrevi um post exatamente sobre esse assunto no blog. Ele é um pouco extenso para ser portado na íntegra para cá: http://a.accioly.7rtc.com/2011/05/java-vs-equals.html

Answer (score 13):

**Resposta** :

Comparação utlizando : "==" **versus** "equals"

**O que é o Heap?**

> O Heap é um local reservado e protegido da JVM (Java Virtual Machine) onde ficam alocados todos os objetos instanciados durante a execução de seu programa... cada um destes objetos possui um endereço de memoria onde está armazenado, e o único acesso a ele, é por via de uma referencia (armazenada fora do heap).... Esta referencia, também possui o endereço de memoria, tornando o seu acesso único e exclusivo a este objeto.
>
> > Quando você usa o operador **"=="** para comparar, você está comparando externa ao heap já
> >     a comparação utilizando **"equals"** seria o inverso do operador **"=="** que compara os objetos dentro do heap, ou seja, suas características.

**Resumindo:**

> **"=="** ----> é usado para comparar dois objetos, verificando se os objetos referenciam ao mesmo lugar na memória.
>   **"equals"** ---> esse método é definido na classe Object, a partir do qual todas as classes ou é um descendente direto ou indireto. Por padrão , o método **equals ()** se comporta o mesmo que o operador **"=="** mas, a classe **String** **substitui(sobrescreve)** o método equals () para comparar os caracteres em uma string e não os seus locais na memória.

**Observação:**

> Além isso é ideal quando criamos um novo objeto, do tipo por exemplo, **Pessoa**(como você criou), sobrescrevermos o método **"equals"** herdado de Object, para podermos ver se as pessoas são realmente iguais. Um exemplo seria se sua classe **Pessoa** possuir os atributos **idade** e **nome** você pode sobrescrever o método **equals** assim:

```
public boolean equals(Pessoa p) {  

      boolean igual = false;  
      if ((this.nome.equals(p.getNome())) && (this.idade == p.getIdade()))  
         igual = true;  

      return igual;  
   }
```

**Referências de pesquisa:**

> > > [Link Programmer Interview](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/)
> > >       [Link Stack Overflow English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)
> > >       [Link JavaFree](http://javafree.uol.com.br/topic-3932-Comparar-variaveis--ou-equals.html)

Answer (score 8):

Quanto à primeira dúvida, você está correto.

Segunda:

Não necessariamente. Em Java o método `Equals()` sempre procura (ou pelo menos deveria, depende da implementação real) encontrar a comparação mais descritiva. Até pode em alguns casos comparar a referência, quando esta for a forma mais descritiva de comparar objetos. Mas a princípio a comparação de referência é evitada, quando possível.

O melhor exemplo é a comparação de *strings*. Duas *strings* idênticas mas em endereços diferentes retornam `true` quando usa-se `Equals` mas `false` quando usa-se `==` (isso é um pouco mais complicado que isto por causa do *interning*, mas isto é outro assunto).

Então para o seu caso específico, até seria a mesma coisa. **A não ser que** a implementação  do `Equals` especifica da classe `Pessoa` mude o comportamento padrão.

Por padrão o Java, através da classe `Object` onde todas as outras classes são derivadas direta ou indiretamente, tem uma implementação do `Equals` que compara as referências.

Mas seria adequado que esta classe `Pessoa` sobrepusesse a implementação padrão com outra que fosse mais descritiva. Que pegasse algum(ns) campo(s) chave(s) e os comparasse para determinar se é a mesma identidade ou não. Estes campos precisariam formar uma chave única, ou seja, nenhuma outra instância da classe poderia ser igual a outra.

Existe esta implementação? Só você pode ver isto, nós não estamos vendo. Você tem que ver nesta classe se há esta implementação e como ela está procedendo.

No [comentário do Anthony Acciolly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34562/comportamento-das-diferentes-formas-de-compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-java/34564#comment66728_34562) acima tem um [link para o blog dele](http://a.accioly.7rtc.com/2011/05/java-vs-equals.html) com um bom exemplo de implementação usando o CPF como identificador único de identidade da pessoa. É uma boa forma de tornar o `Equals` da classe `Pessoa` mais relevante. Note que não tem nada de extraordinariamente errado deixar comparar as referências neste caso. Mas não é o mais intuitivo. O ideal é fazer esta comparação ter uma semântica própria. Veja como ele fez a implementação do `Equals` para a classe pensando nas diversas situações do objeto:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // Um objeto é sempre igual a ele mesmo
    if (this == obj) {
        return true; 
    }
    // Um objeto nunca deve ser igual a null
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    /* Uma pessoa só pode ser igual a outra pessoa.
     * Caso uma pessoa possa ser igual a uma de suas subclasses
     * use !(obj instanceof Pessoa)
     */
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    // Converte a referencia para uma pessoa
    final Pessoa other = (Pessoa) obj;
    // Duas pessoas só podem ser comparadas se possuem CPF
    if (this.cpf == null || other.cpf == null) {
        return false;
    }        
    // Duas pessoas são iguais se possuem o mesmo CPF
    return this.cpf.equals(other.cpf);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/EqualsImplementation.java)

Veja os detalhes da implementação no blog dele (ele gentilmente cedeu este exemplo).

Eu falo disso em mais detalhes [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18910/101). Ela é sobre o C# e tem algumas diferenças para o Java, mas ali explico melhor essa coisa de identidade. Também falo um pouco de identidade aqui [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101).

Comment: Eu tenho duas pequenas críticas em relação a esse exemplo de `equals`: 1) se uma pessoa não tiver um CPF, ela será considerada *diferente de si própria*... Ajuda no começo do `equals` colocar um "teste rápido" `if( this == obj )`, que não só previne casos como esse como potencialmente melhora a performance global. 2) Ao comparar as classes, esse código está fechando esse objeto à possibilidade de extensão - ninguém poderia por exemplo criar uma subclasse de `Pessoa` que ainda pudesse ser comparada a ela por igualdade. Na minha opinião, seria preferível fazer `if( !(obj instanceof Pessoa) )`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr o exemplo não é meu :P Concordo com todos os pontos levantados. É claro que falta um pouco de contexto. Pode ser que se não tiver CPF é uma pessoa inválida, então uma comparação deveria ser falsa sempre. Talvez deveria ser uma exceção se fosse isso, mas sei lá, é só especulação. Talvez a intenção seja que a classe não deva ser estendida.

Comment: @mgibsonbr. Sobre a comparação com a própria referência eu concordo contigo (e de fato, alguns IDES geram o código dessa maneira). Quanto a fechar a possibilidade de extensão, isso foi proposital, você nem sempre quer que um objeto de uma subclasse seja igual ao objeto da própria classe.

Comment: Este site não é fantástico? Todos aprendemos um pouco mais.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Eu imaginei que fosse proposital, mas quis chamar a atenção ao fato de qualquer forma. Há prós e contras em se fazer dessa maneira, acho até que valeria uma pergunta separada sobre o assunto... :P

Comment: Só para mencionar algo que esqueci no blog. Tanto [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained#equals) quanto [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html) possuem facilitadores para implementar o método `equals`.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, perdão por tumultuar os comentários mas atualizei o exemplo no blog conforme suas sugestões (aproveitei para linkar para cá ;). Se vocês quiserem atualizar o exemplo por aqui fiquem a vontade.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly não está tumultuando nada não, pelo contrário, está contribuindo positivamente.

Answer (score 7):

Por padrão, toda classe que não declare extensão de outra classe, por baixo dos panos, ela extenderá [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). Em seu objeto Pessoa, já que você não sobrescreveu o método equals que ele herdou de [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), a comparação será feita assim (código fonte do método equals de [java.lang.Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Se você quiser mudar o comportamento de equals (o que é perfeitamente normal para obedecer um contrato de uma possível entidade por exemplo), geralmente faríamos (resumidamente):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this.id == ((Pessoa) obj).id;
}
```

Aqui você estaria falando que uma Pessoa só é igual a outra **SE** os id forem iguais.

Answer (score 1):

"Aqui sempre é impresso que não é igual, sendo assim creio eu que estou comparando referências correto?"

Correto.

"Minha outra dúvida é se isso é igual ao código acima que foi digitado"

Não é igual. Você mesmo pode definir qual é o critério que torna duas pessoas "iguais" e implementar esse critério no método `public boolean equals(Object o)` da mesma classe que, com o auxílio da anotação `@Override`, sobrescreverá o método herdado da classe `Object`. Exemplo: duas pessoas são iguais se o CPF delas são iguais. Existem alguns critérios que devem ser seguidos (contratos), principalmente com o método `compareTo` da interface `Comparable`. Aconselho dar uma olhada nesses contratos também, principalmente para seguir os padrões da comunidade e tornar seu código mais robusto.