# Diferença do StringBuffer.equals() e String.equals() no Java

Tags: java, string, equals, stringbuffer

O comportamento do método `equals()` da classe `StringBuffer` do Java é diferente do `equals()` da classe `String`?

Se sim, como iria sobrescrever isso?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

[`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) usa a implementação que vem de `Object` conforme demonstra as outras respostas. Mas a comparação não é de uma *string* e sim de uma [referência para uma *string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2192068/221800). Como todo `Object` faz por padrão se o método não for sobrescrito. Ou seja está havendo uma comparação se o objeto é o mesmo, se ele está apontando para a mesma posição da memória. É claro que se se está na mesma posição, o conteúdo é igual, mas o contrário pode não ser verdadeiro. É possível ter dois conteúdos iguais em posições diferentes da memória. Por isso você testar se dois objetos `StringBuffer` são iguais em seu conteúdo não dá um resultado confiável a não ser que você escreva um algoritmo para isto (O Math escreveu na resposta dele). Ele poderá retornar `false` quando na verdade o conteúdo, na prática, é igual e apenas a referência é diferente.

Já `String` [sobrescreve a implementação](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) com uma própria comparando cada caractere individualmente (também dá para ver o código na resposta do Math).

Uma *string* em Java se for igual pode ter um sistema chamado [interning](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34564/101). Se puder ser identificado que existem duas variáveis do tipo `string` iguais, não haverá duas alocações, haverá apenas um objeto e as variáveis apontarão para o mesmo local da memória. Neste caso tanto a referência quanto o conteúdo retornarão `true`. Nos demais casos poderá retornar `false` para a referência e `true` para o conteúdo.

Answer (score 4):

Eles são diferentes.

Implementação do método `equals()` na classe String.java:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String) anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                        return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Implementação do método `equals()` na classe StringBuffer.java:

```
//não há
```

Logo, quando se chama o método `equals()` em um objeto do tipo StringBuffer o método chamado é o da classe Object:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

A diferença entre eles é que o `equals()` da classe String compara o conteúdo dos objetos, ou seja, a sequencia de caracteres que o objeto armazena, e retorna *true* caso eles sejam iguais, independente se pertencem a objetos diferentes. Enquanto o método `equals()` da classe StringBuffer compara as referências, e só retorna *true* se estiver comparando **exatamente** o mesmo objeto com ele mesmo, independente de seus conteúdos. <sup>([Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3905/3117) pode exemplificar melhor o comportamento do `equals()` da classe String.)</sup>

Você não pode sobrescrever nenhum dos dois, pois as classes são marcadas como `final` o que impede que elas sejam herdadas e consequentemente ter seus métodos sobrescritos. Cada classe tem seu propósito específico, se quiser comparar Strings basta chamar o método `equals()` normalmente, entretanto se quiser comparar StringBuffers, precisará chamar o método `toString()` de cada uma delas antes de chamar o método `equals()`. Exemplo:

```
public class CompStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer("teste");
        StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer("teste");
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
        System.out.println(s1.toString().equals(s2.toString()));
    }
}
```

Resultado:

> false
>   true

Answer (score -2):

Não há diferença nenhuma porque nos dois casos o método é o mesmo. O metodo `equals` pertence a classe [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) e tanto a classe `String` e `StringBuilder` herdam a classe `Object`.

Para sobrescrever o método, o principio é o mesmo para sobrescrever qualquer método na linguagem java.  Use a notação `@Override`

Comment: O método `equals()` é sobrescrito na classe String, o que o torna diferente do método `equals()` da classe Object.

Comment: Outra coisa que só lembrei depois: tb não é possível sobrescrever os métodos das classes String e StringBuffer pois elas são marcadas como _final_, logo não é possível herdá-las. (Melhorei e apaguei o comentário anterior pois precisava colocar algumas palavras no plural para ficar mais claro o que eu quis dizer).