# Método com foreach só retorna false

Tags: java, foreach

Eu tenho um método que vai verificar se a dívida é igual a zero(`divida == "0"`). Se for ele retorna `true`, senão retorna `false`.

Código:

```
    for(String divida : dividas){
        return divida == "0";
        System.out.println(divida+"\n"+b);
    }
    return false;
```

Ele só retorna `false`, por que o primeiro elemento é diferente de zero, mas o segundo é igual, e continua sendo `false`.

O que faço?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você deve usar o `equals` para comparar o conteúdo da string, o `==` testa a referencia.

```
    for(String divida : dividas){
        return (divida.equals("0"))
```

Quer entender mais sobre comparações no Java?
 Da uma lida nessa questão e suas respostas: [Comportamento das diferentes formas de comparação em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34562/comportamento-das-diferentes-formas-de-compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-java/34566#34566).

Adicionando código conforme comentario:

```
    boolean retorno = false;
    for(String divida : dividas){
        if(retorno = divida.equals("0")) {
            break;
        }
    }       
    return retorno;
```

Comment: Continua do mesmo jeito, se o primeiro elemento(ou o que vem antes) for diferente de zero retorna tudo false.

Comment: Entendi onde está o erro, é que toda vez que eu ia verificar se é igual a zero só verificava o primeiro e retornava, E acontecia o mesmo processo sempre.

Comment: @lucasdaniel adicionei um bloco

Comment: Mas se retorna `false` ele vai executar outro código.

Comment: Eu colocaria `return true;` dentro do bloco do `if` e `return false;` fora. Com isso eu não caio na má prática de programação de atribuir a variável na condição do `if` e nem mesmo preciso dessa variável. E também não preciso do `break;`.