# Dúvida sobre o IF

Tags: java, if

A função IF só funciona com Inteiros ou também funciona com String? Eu estava tentando criar um programa que perguntaria se você tem certeza que deseja criar a senha. Você pode verificar o código abaixo:

```
package com.programas.Verificacao2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VoceTemCertezaVerifi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     int campo1 = 0, campo2 = 0;
     int sim = 0, não = 0;

     String s = "sim";


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Digite Sua Senha:");
      campo1 = in.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Digite novamente sua senha:");
      campo2 = in.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Você tem certeza?");
      s = in.nextLine();

      if(s == sim) {System.out.println("Senha Criada.");}else{
          if(s == não) {System.out.println("Ação Cancelada");
      }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Acho que responde => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34562/91

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Para comparar string, use [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

```
String opcao = "sim";

  if(opcao.equals("sim")){
   System.out.println("Senha Criada.");
  else{
    System.out.println("Ação Cancelada");
  }
```

Pelo código postado, você pode alterar a validação para que receba uma `String`, depois basta comparar usando o exemplo acima:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

     int campo1 = 0, campo2 = 0;
     String confirmacao;
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Digite Sua Senha:");
      campo1 = in.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Digite novamente sua senha:");
      campo2 = in.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Você tem certeza?(Digite sim ou nao)");
      confirmacao = in.next();

  if(confirmacao.equals("sim")) {
    System.out.println("Senha Criada.");
    }else{
          System.out.println("Ação Cancelada");
      }
    }
```

Outra alternativa é usar `switch`, assim se a pessoa não digitar nada e der <kbd>enter</kbd>, é possível exibir uma mensagem diferente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int campo1 = 0, campo2 = 0;
        String confirmacao;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite Sua Senha:");
        campo1 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Digite novamente sua senha:");
        campo2 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Você tem certeza?(Digite sim ou nao)");
        confirmacao = in.next();

        switch (confirmacao) {
            case "sim":
                System.out.println("Senha Criada.");
                break;
            case "nao":
                System.out.println("Ação Cancelada");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Opção digitada inválida");
        }
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta rapida.

Comment: @DanielT Disponha :D Caso a resposta tenha ajudado a esclarecer sua dúvida, não esqueça de marcar como aceita, clicando no `v` logo abaixo do contador a esquerda.

Comment: Gostaria de saber porque o -1. Se faltou algo na resposta, sem saber o que foi, não vou conseguir melhorar.

Comment: Eu devo ter clicado sem querer no -1, eu já retirei, a sua respsta foi completa

Comment: @DanielT sem problemas :)

Comment: Acho que faltou coisa sim na resposta, e você pode complementa-la Diego: o principal problema do código na questão não é a comparação com `==`  (que é uma comparação válida de string em quase todas as linguagens de alto-nível populares) - mas sim, o fato de o "sim" e o "nao"  do código na pergunta estarem sem aspas. Com isso eles são tratados como nomes de variáveis, não como texto. (eu sei que você sabe disso - só estou pedindo para colocar na resposta)

Comment: @jsbueno pior que ele tratou como int, e nem havia percebido, para mim, eram variaveis de string sim e nao. Mas é válida a sugestão. vou editar a resposta com base no código dele.

Comment: @jsbueno ficou boa agora?

Comment: :-)  agora está legal.

Comment: Já resolvi meu problema,