# Duvida sobre java.util.Date

Tags: java

Alguem me consegue explicar o que isto vai retornar:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.util.Date date1 = date;
java.util.Date date2 = (java.util.Date(date.clone()));
System.out.println(date==date1);
System.out.println(date==date2);
System.out.println(date.equals(date2)));
```

Comment: Do jeito que está 2 erros! 2 linhas tem problemas nessa `java.util.Date date2 = (java.util.Date(date.clone()));` e nessa `System.out.println(date.equals(date2)));`

Comment: e para nao dar erro teria de ficar como?

Comment: eu resolvi escrever uma resposta e explicar também os problemas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem problemas em *duas* linhas:

Nessa:

```
java.util.Date date2 = (java.util.Date(date.clone()));
```

o correto é fazer um `cast` para `java.util.Date` porque `clone()` retorna o tipo `Object`:

```
java.util.Date date2 = (java.util.Date)date.clone();
```

---

e nessa:

```
System.out.println(date.equals(date2)));
```

tem um parenteses a mais, só remover o último.

---

***Código completo e sem problemas:***

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.util.Date date1 = date;
java.util.Date date2 = (java.util.Date)date.clone();
System.out.println(date==date1); // saída: true
System.out.println(date==date2); // saída: false
System.out.println(date.equals(date2)); // saída: true
```

[***Exemplo Online***](http://ideone.com/gdjs4h)

No próprio [site já tem uma pergunta e respostas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18910/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-no-uso-do-m%C3%A9todo-equals-para-o-operador) que pode esclarecer os motivos dos resultados obtidos nas operações.

***Leitura:***

- [Diferença entre equals e ==](http://www.guj.com.br/t/resolvido-diferenca-entre-equals-e/134051)
- [Como comparar Strings em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3905/como-comparar-strings-em-java)
- [Qual a diferença no uso do método Equals para o operador ==?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18910/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-no-uso-do-m%C3%A9todo-equals-para-o-operador)

Comment: e sabe-me dizer o que vai retornar ??

Comment: Editado .... @StinRose, no exemplo online tem também as resposta!

Comment: Eu acho que é true, false, false... estou certa ?

Comment: @StinRose eu editei e coloquei um link para leitura sobre as saídas.

Comment: Sim já percebi ! Muito obrigada !